# OpenLayers: filter radius

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, cql

I am trying to filter a points layer to only show points within a given radius. I have determined the best method to do this is a CQL_FILTER using DWITHIN. When I set this param and then load the map, I get broken tiles. Here is the snippet of my code in question:

```
var elecs = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
"Elec",
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
    {
    layers: "UVC:Elec_3790",
    transparent: "true",
    styles:"Elecs",
    format: "image/png",
    cql_filter: "DWITHIN(the_geom, Point(-79, 39), 50, kilometers)"
 },
    {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
);
```

Removing the cql_filter line loads the map normally again but without a radius filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the broken tiles, but GeoServer only supports unit of measure based searches if the data backend is Oracle at the moment (as of version 2.2-RC1)

Comment: Not even postgres will work, only with Oracle. Adding full support for units, and metric distances over data in lat/lon is possible, but no trivial. We have been waiting for someone to pour the days of work needed on this for quite a bit of time, or someone that would sponsor the development, but no one popped up so far.

Comment: Is this still true 9 years later?

Comment: More or less... now the postgis backend supports units too, but there still not generalized support for them across all data sources.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up just using WITHIN and passing a POLYGON of a circle computed on the client so I wouldn't have to use DWITHIN because it was giving me too many issues.